# How to rotate camera so it faces/above point on sphere (Three.js)

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, perspectivecamera

I'm wondering if anyone has an idea on how to rotate a camera so the camera faces directly above a point on the sphere.

UPDATE

Radio's answer is correct. After some debugging it looks like my coordinates were reversed.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kbtn6pz5/

This moves the camera over a random point on the sphere, applies a lookAt property and then sets the altitude of the camera over the sphere's surface.

Based on the fiddle boilerplate...

```
    var camera, scene, renderer, geometry, material, mesh;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);




    scene.add(camera);
        var rad = 200;
    geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( rad, 32, 32 );
    material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);

    var point = THREE.GeometryUtils.randomPointsInGeometry( geometry, 1 );

    var altitude = 100;

    var coeff = 1+ altitude/rad;

    camera.position.x = point[0].x * coeff;
    camera.position.y = point[0].y * coeff;
    camera.position.z = point[0].z * coeff;
    camera.lookAt(mesh.position);

    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();

}


function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Comment: You, sir, are amazing. This is such a quality response that has saved me serious headbanging. Thank you so much! My major issues looking back were not changing all xyz positions of the camera and setting camera.lookAt(0,0,0,) it needs the 0's in a vector 3 which has really prevented  me from doing some good guess and check. Setting it to my world position alleviated this. Thank you again. I am working on a 3D Earthquake Visualization...hopefully you will see it sometime. Your help has made wrapping it up possible!

Comment: Would love to see it. @Radio this conversation when it's available.